# max(max(col1), max(col2), ...) does not work

Tags: postgresql, max

I have a table with three integer columns:

```
select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3) from mytable
```

I want the max of both three columns. But this does not work:

```
select max(max(col1), max(col2), max(col3)) from mytable
```

How to get this done?

I use PostgreSQL, but I hope that this can be solved with standard SQL.

Answer (score 6):

That should be [`GREATEST()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST), not `MAX()`. `MAX()` is for aggregating over values from rows, `GREATEST()` is for aggregating over a list of values (from columns, expressions).

You can either find the 3 max values, one for each column and then the greatest of the three:

```
select greatest(max(col1), max(col2), max(col3)) 
from mytable ;
```

or find the greatest value in each row and then the max over all of them:

```
select max(greatest(col1, col2, col3)) 
from mytable ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In our MS SQL Server 2008 database we have several levels of prices for products and I use something like this to get MAX and MIN prices for each product:

```
select price_1, price_2, price_3, price_4,  price_6, max_price
    from prices
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(d) max_price FROM (VALUES (price_1),(price_2),(price_3),(price_4),(price_6)) AS a(d)) A
```